# Trying to get property 'data' of non-object when fetching data using CURL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, error-handling

I am building a Laravel application whereby I am using CURL to fetch data from an external API and populate my web pages. The Curl function which should perform a GET request was working well initially but I have tried today and it throws an error of

**(1/1) ErrorException Trying to get property 'data' of non-object**

which am finding hard to debug.. The data the error is referring to is the first line of code in the travel function indicated below.

Kindly assist?

**My Controller code**

```
   public
    function travel()
    {

 
        $cover_options = $this->global_Curl_get('api/travel/cover-options')->data;
        $countries = $this->global_Curl_get('api/general/countries')->data;
        return view('B2C::travel.travel')->with(['coveroptions' => $cover_options, 'countries' => $countries]);
    }
```

**global_Curl_get function**

```
 public function global_Curl_get($url)
    {
        //dd($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url);
        $ch = curl_init();
        // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => ($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url),
        ));
        // Send the request & save response to $resp
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: If you're getting an error about a *non-object*, then it means that the Curl call isn't returning you valid JSON. Inspect the result of the `curl_exec` call and you'll find out what's going on.

Comment: @iainn Thanks the problem was third party API endpoint was not pushing any data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your function is returning an array of data.
You could try something like this.

```
function travel()
 {
    $cover_options = $this->global_Curl_get('api/travel/cover-options');

    $countries = $this->global_Curl_get('api/general/countries');
    return view('B2C::travel.travel')->with(['coveroptions' => $cover_options['data'], 'countries' => $countries['data']]);
}
```

Comment: can you provide a vardump of $cover_options maybe it is json_encoded data